# How much and what kind of evidence is needed in order to improve on "cherry picked" information?

Tags: philosophy-of-science

How much and what kind of evidence is needed in order to improve on "cherry picked" information?

If e.g. citing only a few studies constitutes cherry picking, just as citing small sample sizes could.

OTOH, in some sense such picks may be all evidence there is, so are they still somehow wrong, if they're the best available?

Comment: If they are "all evidence there is" then they are not cherry picked. The number of studies and sample sizes do not matter in cherry picking, the point is that from *all the evidence available* only that which favors the desired conclusion is picked. Although if the studies are few and the sample sizes small, drawing any grand conclusions would be [overgeneralization fallacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Misuse_of_statistics#Overgeneralization). One should simply withhold judgment and collect more evidence until it becomes representative. Statisticians have numerical measures for that.

Comment: @Conifold Okay so maybe there's also a false accusation of cherry picking, when "all evidence there is" is unfavorable, even when someone would like that "more evidence" would change the interpretations.